# Mapping Hibernate entity for unknown DiscriminatorValue for InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a classic Hibernate `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)` with `@DiscriminatorFormula`. It works fine. However, there are about 500 different values for the `@DiscriminatorValue` in the database and I need map just about 30 of them to Java classes (children) and the rest of them to map to the parent Java class.

The problem can be modelled as an example inheritance on Animal class.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorFormula("...")
public class Animal implements Serializable {
  ...
  @Column
  public String getName() { ... }
}
```

So I have have about 30 subclasses of Animal defined in the Java code with `@DiscriminatorValue`. When Hibernate founds unknown value for the discriminator, then it throws `WrongClassException`. However, I need to map these unknown discriminator values  to one entity, the best it the Animal class. (I need to use only the method getName() in such cases.)

I know one solution is to put a SQL CASE into the `@DiscriminatorFormula` but then I have to state there all 30 known discriminator values (plus more when I will need to add others). So I am looking for more flexible solution.

P.S. It is a legacy code, so I cannot change the model.

Comment: Very good question indeed! I am afraid you are stuck to the SQL CASE solution. Something like a `forceDefault=true` option (map to root class instead of exception) for the `@DiscriminatorColumn` or `@DiscriminatorFormula` annotation would be nice to have. Is the `@DiscriminatorValue` on the root class also missing in your working code or just in the example? If no, maybe you can force the default mapping this way. Cannot try it out right now but I doubt it, if `@DiscriminatorColumn` is used a default value is generated for a missing `@DiscriminatorValue`.

Comment: `@DiscriminatorValue` has been missing in the code and in the example, too. And this little detail persuaded me to dig into the Hibernate code once again and find the solution. See bellow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[tscho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/994168/tscho) has pointed me in the right direction, so I was able to find a solution for my case. The `@DiscriminatorValue` evaluates special values `@DiscriminatorValue("null")` and `@DiscriminatorValue("not null")`. The second one is the right for me.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorFormula("...")
@DiscriminatorValue("not null")
public class Animal implements Serializable {
  ...
  @Column
  public String getName() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Very nice! Can you provide a link where this is documented or is it only _documented in the code_?

Comment: I have found it in the code, see the class SingleTableEntityPersister. You can find some sources by [Google search](https://www.google.cz/search?q=hibernate%20discriminator%20value%20null). Otherwise I cannot find it the official docs.

Answer (score 5):

Good news. I have just documented this behavior in the new User Guide. This is the [JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10966) issue.

Basically, you have two options:

- `@DiscriminatorValue("not null")` as a fall-back strategy when there is no explicit discriminator value mapping matching the underlying database column value.
- `@DiscriminatorValue("null")` for when the database column value is null. Usually, you'd use this for the base class.

There's a detailed example on the [Hibernate blog as well](http://in.relation.to/2016/07/19/null-andnot-null-discriminator-values/).