# Default class for Hibernate Single Table Inheritance Scheme

Tags: hibernate-mapping

I have an application that maps views into an existing Hibernate schema that makes extensive use of single table inheritance with a discriminator-value in the CLASSNAME column. What makes my situation unusual is that I do not what to support all the subclasses (discriminator-value in the Hibernate mappings) in the data, just those of interest to the application.

The problem is that if the application encounters an unsupported discriminator-value, Hibernate throws a "org.hibernate.WrongClassException" because it cannot find a mapping with the required discriminator-value.

What I would like to do is to create subclass that Hibernate will use if the discriminator-value is unknown (instead of throwing an exception).

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
Ed

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here for those using annotation:

[Mapping Hibernate entity for unknown DiscriminatorValue for InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272660/mapping-hibernate-entity-for-unknown-discriminatorvalue-for-inheritancetype-sing).

What this does not tell you is what to use in a mapping file. I checked the open source code and it appears that the discriminator-value="<not null discriminator>" will do the trick. Hibernate checks for this value (and <null discriminator>), and gives them special handling.