# Hibernate Inheritance - set relation to null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I try to understand why Hibernate adds the name of my model in the values when inserting (JPA save), but I can't figure out why.

Here is entity model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "person_type")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "username", unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "person_type", insertable = false))
    @AnyMetaDef(idType = "int", metaType = "string",
            metaValues = {
                    @MetaValue(targetEntity = Candidate.class, value = "CANDIDATE"),
                    @MetaValue(targetEntity = Company.class, value = "COMPANY"),
            })
    @JoinColumn(name="person_id", insertable = false)
    private Object person = null;
}
```

Polymorphism works perfectly. The problem is that when I register a new user who by default is supposed to have `person_type` and `person_id` set to null, the query performed is the following:

```
insert into `USER` (`email`, `password`, `username`, `person_type`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, 'User')
```

Code to insert :
user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
userRepository.save(user);

I even tried adding the line `user.setPerson(null)` before the insert, but it's the same.

Any idea please?

Comment: A discriminator column cannot be `null`. So it will be set to `User` in this case. If it isn't a discriminator column for the `User` then remove that.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum. Just found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272660/mapping-hibernate-entity-for-unknown-discriminatorvalue-for-inheritancetype-sing

Comment: afaik you don't even need the `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)` and `@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "person_type")` as the discriminator is for a linked entity **not** the user class itself.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, the base class needs to be a non-entity class and be annotated with `@MappedSuperclass`.

I.e. you need an `@MappedSuperclass BaseUser.class` and then extend that for
`@Entity User extends BaseUser` and `@Entity SuperUser extends BaseUser`.

[VladMihalcea - Inherit from base class JPA/Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-inherit-properties-from-a-base-class-entity-using-mappedsuperclass-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: I don't understand why? My polymorphism works fine when i set a candidate or company. It's just that by default I want to add a user with no default relationship, i.e. null. In my main example `CANDIDATE` and `COMPANY` are entities.

Moreover, these entities do not share any property with the user model, it is simply that the user is always linked either to a company or to a candidate

Answer (score 0):

Just add `@DiscriminatorValue("null")` to the User entity.

Detailed answer: [Mapping Hibernate entity for unknown DiscriminatorValue for InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272660/mapping-hibernate-entity-for-unknown-discriminatorvalue-for-inheritancetype-sing)